# Asp.Net Core get json array from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I met a problem when retrieving the json array set in appsettings.json.

When using **Configuration.GetSection("xxx").GetChildren()** to get json array, and the return value is null. Then I used the way below to solve the problem, and it worked.

**In appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "EndPointConfiguration": [
    {
      "UserName": "TestUser",
      "Email": "Test@global.com"
    },
    {
      "UserName": "TestUser",
      "Email": "Test@global.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Then I create the class:**

```
public class EndPointConfiguration 
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**Finally, using an array of the EndPointConfiguration class will work:**

```
var endPointConfiguration = Configuration.GetSection("EndPointConfiguration").Get<EndPointConfiguration[]>();
```

I am pretty new to .net core, do not why the Configuration.GetSection().GetChildren() cannot work. Can anyone proficient help to give an answer? Thanks.

Comment: getChildren returns a list of `IConfigurationSection` which is a section defined by a key and having a value([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationsection?view=aspnetcore-2.2)). An array of objects is not a `IConfigurationSection` as it does not contain a string key to be referenced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetChildren()` method will return you `IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection>`, which is great if working with simple types such as a list of strings. For instance:

```
{
  "EndPointUsernames": [
      "TestUser1",
      "TestUser2",
      "TestUser3",
      "TestUser4"
   ]
}
```

can easily be added to a string array without the need to define a separate class such as `EndPointConfiguration` as you have. From here you could simply call

```cs
string[] userNames = Configuration.GetSection("EndPointUsernames").GetChildren().ToArray().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
```

to retrieve these values. You've done it correctly in your example as you've strongly typed the results to a list of `EndPointConfiguration` objects.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining!